# Connected graph with two vertices of odd degrees, not containing an Euler path?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

The rules for an Euler path is:

> A graph will contain an Euler path if it contains at most two vertices
> of odd degree.

My graphs are undirected and connected and fulfill the above condition.

Yet these two graphs have no Eulerian path. Why is it so?

[image: graph1]
[image: graph2]

Comment: both of them have 4 vertices with odd degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These graphs do not have Eulerian paths because they have more than two vertices of odd degree. In this case, both have four vertices of odd degree, which is more than 2.

I have gone through and circled and labeled all of the vertices with odd degree so you can check over which vertices you may have missed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got confused by the square I believe.